# hadoop input data problems

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I'm having trouble with the map functions:
The original data is stored in the tsv file:
I just want the last two columns saved:
the first is the original node(383), second is the target(4575), third is the weight(1)

383 4575    1

383 4764    1

383 5458    1

383 5491    1

```
         public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,OutputCollector output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] tokens = line.split("t");

        int weight = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
        int target = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);

    }
```

Here is my code:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException  InterruptedException
  {
  String line = value.toString();
  //split  the tsv file 
  String[] tokens = line.split("/t");
  //save the weight and target    
  private Text target = Integer.parsetxt(tokens[0]);
  int weight = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
  context.write(new Text(target), new Intwritable(weight) );
  }
}


public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> 
{
@Override
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,Context context)
throws IOException, InterruptedException 
{
 //initialize the  count variable
    int weightsum = 0;
       for (IntWritable value : values) {
        weightsum += value.get();
 }
         context.write(key, new IntWritable(weightsum));
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

String[] tokens = line.split("t");

should be

String[] tokens = line.split("\t");

Comment: that's all? Thank you

Comment: private Text target = Integer.parsetxt(tokens[0]); I dont think we have parsetxt ?? Instead i think we need to have Text target = new Text(tokens[0]).

Answer (score 0):

split with spaces.

```
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");

    private Text target = Integer.parsetxt(tokens[1]);
    int weight = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
```